# JavaScript download and unzip file

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am developing web app using Sencha ExtJS. I have to download ZIP file and extract the contents (uncompressed) in my web app. I have tried [JSZip](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip) and [JSUnZip](https://github.com/augustl/js-unzip). Both are not working.

Could anyone know how to download and extract contents (uncompressed) zip file in JavaScript.

--Sridhar

Comment: javascript has no filesystem access, so you have no chance to extract a zip file

Comment: if you have access to server-side code, you can create a method/function to take a zip file from a form submit client-side.  From client-side perspective you would create an upload field and submit the form. [More info on that in sencha docs](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.File)

Comment: @Jandalf, I dont have to access file system, the zip file is received from the server side. I am using AJAX request to hit server.

Comment: @SridharBoganathan, ok google give me this:
https://github.com/mattgodbolt/jsunzip

Comment: @Jandalf, It is not working with Sencha framework (touch / extjs). but it is working as described in examples with normal ajax request. how we make it working within secha framework.

Comment: @SridharBoganathan what is the error? or maybe you try another library...

Comment: @Jandalf, no errors. It gives undefined for result.files. do we have any other JavaScript framework to do the same.

Comment: @SridharBoganathan: https://www.google.de/search?q=javascript+unzip try some, I have not tested them.